# Apps auto updating even if disabled?

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I have been using Android for a couple of days now (coming form iOS), so I am not familiar with it.

I have disabled automatic update of apps in the Play Store. Nevertheless, I received a couple of notifications stating "14 apps have been updated", or the like. I have now lost such notification, so I cannot replicate its text exactly (I do not know if there is any way of recovering it).

What could the cause be?

Answer (score 1):

In Play Store settings set "Auto-update apps" to "Do not auto-update apps". And it is now off.

What might have happened:

1. You received a notification that there are apps that HAVE updates but have not yet been updated. In this case it just notifies you and asks for further actions.
2. The update process might have started automatically before you disabled the updates. In this case all apps that started updating will finish updating but after that no further auto-updating will occur.

Comment: 1. I think it is not the case, although as long as I do not have a sample notification I am not certain.  2. This is likely not the case either, but the same as before applies.  If this ever happens again, I can come back.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the setting for auto-update in the Playstore app, this affects only apps you install *thereafter* (it's the default to set on installation of new apps). If you don't want your already installed apps to auto-update, you've got to check with each of them:

1. Open the Playstore app
2. Navigate to "My Apps" (via the "Hamburger menu")
3. Open the settings for each app you don't want to auto-update, and uncheck the auto-update setting

[image: auto-update] [image: auto-update]
<sup>Auto-update check box (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Also see [this howto](http://tunecomp.net/android-chrome-auto-update/) for a complete walk-through with screenshots (second screenshot above comes from there). Location and "visuals" of that check-box might depend on the version of the playstore app, but the principle should stay the same.

Note that for some "system apps" (usually parts of the "Google Apps") you might not be able to turn this off. I've e.g. experienced that for *Google Play Services* on some devices.

Comment: What you say is strange. This is a corporate phone. There are at least two apps (say, A1 and A2) that were already installed when I got the phone (which was brand new). The settings were likely the standard defaults for Android 5.1.1 (I don't think my corporation takes care of changing this for their standard deployed mobiles). I might have installed a few other apps before disabling autoupdates. But even A1 and A2 have the autoupdate box unchecked, and I did not do it.

Comment: That is indeed strange, @sancho.s – as auto-update is the default. No idea what might be behind that specific case – but what I described with my answer was what I've experienced on all devices I've checked. Admittedly, their number was limited.